PHP post to remote API with curl
I want to post to this api:
Fields:

Name    Type    
id* INTEGER 
date*   DATE    
hours*  FLOAT   

Here is an example json post request:
POST /api/v1/chase HTTP/1.1
Host: chamos.postos
Authorization: bearer 123123123
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 63

{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2023-12-12",
    "hours": "4.3"
}

Here is how I send the post request:
function call($url, $method = 'GET', $data= null) {
  $api = 'https://chamos.postos.com/api/v1/';
  $token = '123123123';
  $api_url = $api . $url;

  $curl = curl_init($api_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
      'Authorization: bearer ' . $token,
      'Accept: application/json',
  ]);

  if ($method === 'POST') {
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      if ($requestData) {
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
      }
  }

  $res= curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  if (!$res) {
      return false;
  }

  return json_decode($res, true);
}
// some data that is passed down from js:
function post($formData) {
  $data= [
        'id' => $id,
        'date' => $date,
        'hours' => $hours
    ];
  return call('/chase', 'POST', $data);
}

Somehow, this is incorrect as I am recieving the following response from the remote api:

code: 400
details : Array(3)
0 : "id"
1 : "date"
2 : "hours"
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
message : "Missing required fields"

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

First thing to check: check whether the data items were actually successfully passed from JS to PHP

@KenLee Yes it is, I added some logging, I can see the data is passed down to the api call function at least. Maybe the problem is how I create the header?

I don't know whether your API only accepts exactly the header data in your sample one, if it is, then you may need to add in the header Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 and
Content-Length: [value] --- use strlen or something similar to get the "value"

@KenLee Going to test that and will let you know :)

@KenLee Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 did it. Content length wasnt necessary. I read somewhere that it is set automatically by curl? You can answer the question so I can upvote the correct answer if you can please. Thanks for your help

According to the sample post request
POST /api/v1/chase HTTP/1.1
Host: chamos.postos
Authorization: bearer 123123123
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 63

According to PHP official documentation - curl_setopt:
.... cURL automatically sets headers (like content-type: multipart/form-data; content-length...) when you pass an array into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS....
So we may ignore the line with Content-Length: xxx, and all you need to do is to have Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 in the header, so please add it so that your header become like
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
      'Authorization: bearer ' . $token,
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
  ]);

